# How to trace function calls in a Docker container

Tags: docker, zipkin, opentracing, distributed-tracing

Can someone please suggest any way to trace function calls inside a Docker container? I was recommended to use Zipkin, but I am having troubles finding any documentation explaining how to make it work.

Comment: How would it be different from tracing outside of a docker container? Which part troubles you exactly?

Comment: @jabbson Typically I launch docker containers from a third party image and I use it as a black box. I am confused about what I should do. Do I need to add instrument code and then recompile the application inside of the docker container?